# Custom liquid block retrieving context variables

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

How can I retrieve an assigned variable from within a custom Liquid Block in jekyll markdown?

I've read [using assignments in templates](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Programmers#using-assignments-in-templates), but I'm clearly missing something simple.

**EDIT**: This is only happens with Jekyll variables, not basic variables set in liquid.

Does not work:

**The liquid block in markdown:**

```
{% assign variable = site.variables | where "someval", "true" %}

{% customblock variable %}
{% endcustomblock %}
```

**The Jekyll Plugin:**

```
module Jekyll
  module Tags
    class CustomBlockTag < Liquid::Block

      def initialize(tag_name, variable_name, options)
        super
        @variable = variable_name
      end

      def render(context)
          puts context.scopes
          puts context.key?(@variable)
          puts context.find_variable(@variable)
          puts context[@variable] 
      end
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('customblock', Jekyll::Tags::CustomBlockTag)
```

**The output:**

```
{..., "variable"=> {<another map>} }
true
<blank>
<blank>
```

I don't use ruby very often, but as far as I can see in the [source](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/liquid/Liquid/Context), it's just wrapping a dictionary lookup. What am I missing here?

---

The following works fine

**The liquid block in markdown:**

```
{% assign variable = "1" %}

{% customblock variable %}
{% endcustomblock %}
```

**The Jekyll Plugin:**

```
module Jekyll
  module Tags
    class CustomBlockTag < Liquid::Block

      def initialize(tag_name, variable_name, options)
        super
        @variable = variable_name
      end

      def render(context)
          puts context.scopes
          puts context.key?(@variable)
          puts context.find_variable(@variable)
          puts context[@variable] 
      end
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('customblock', Jekyll::Tags::CustomBlockTag)
```

**The output:**

```
{..., "variable"=>"1"}
true
1
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `{% assign variable = site.variables | where "someval", "true" %}` to `{% assign variable = site.variables | where: "someval", "true" %}`.

Also, it doesn't look like `variable` is an option according to the [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/). If you want to pass more information you'll need to use something like `site.data` or information defined in your jekyll initializer (usually called `_config.yml`).

Comment: My MCVE was written in haste. See the edit. I did try this with my actual code and got the same unexpected results of no value.

Comment: I'll mark this correct because I think this is just unsupported usage. 

I believe jekyll/liquid would prefer the user to use existing liquid blocks and access jekyll data from liquid templates, instead of passing jekyll data directly into the plugin system. This is unfortunate because it requires  more copy & paste.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few red herrings that turned out to be the issue:

- my `variable` is actually a [Drop](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/drops/drop.rb) and is not a normal hash value. Specifically, it's a [DocumentDrop](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/drops/document_drop.rb) which delegates `to_s` to the [Document](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/document.rb) class.
- The implementation of `to_s` prints out either the `Document`'s `output`, `content`, or `"NO CONTENT"`.
- In my case, `output` and `content` were either a space or newline character, so that's all that was output. This is because the files only exist for their front matter, so there's no actual content.
- The front matter is accessed via the Drop interface. So I was actually getting `variable`, there was just an empty string representation of it.
- Without further ado, **to access the front matter data**: `context[@variable]["my-front-matter-data"]`

Well at least I feel less like a ruby newbie now.

Comment: Nice job. Congrats on figuring it out